# How to stop iterating a sequence when a condition is met

Tags: clojure

Other than loop .. recur, what is the best Clojure construct to use so that while traversing a sequence of sequences (sos), the processing can stop if a result is found?

Here are the details:

I have a lazy sequence returned from clojure-csv, an sos.

There is a value at a given position (index) in each sequence within the sos.

I keep looking at that position in each sequence until the value is found or
the end of sos is reached.

If the value is found, I want to stop processing the sos.

The only thing I can think of is using a for with when and an into to retain the match, but the sequence processing won't stop, or use filter.

However, I believe I can use something better, but I'm stuck as to what that would be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
(defn find-first [pred col]
  (first (filter pred col)))
```

Then you can do this as an example:

```
(find-first #(< % 5) coll)
```

You should be able to make a predicate that works with a sequence of sequences.

```
user=> (defn find-first [pred col]
  (first (filter pred col)))
#'user/find-first
user=> (find-first #(> % 10) '(1 5 8 2 15 20 31 5 1))
15
```

Comment: What I have to do to make this solution work, is extract a column, and make a sequence out of its values.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer take-while for such tasks and if the key is at a fixed
Index nth could match for it.

```
(take-while #(not= (nth % index) key) sos)

user> (def sos [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9] [10 11 12]])
#'user/sos
user> (take-while #(not= (nth %  2) 9) sos)
([1 2 3] [4 5 6])
```

You could then map your processing function over the resulting sequence.

Answer (score 4):

`for` with `:while` can be used like:

```
(for [s sos :while (not (= (nth s index) val))]  
     s) ;;or do something with s
```

Answer (score 1):

When just searching for the first occurence, I would use `drop-while`. Indeed, `filter` will process the whole sequence which is not useful. (and what if you want to use infinite sequences ?)

**EDIT**: Don't take this into account. Indeed, `filter` returns a lazy sequence.

```
(defn find-first
  [pred coll]
  (first (drop-while #(not (pred %)) coll))
```

Comment: For me, I'm not seeing `filter` process the whole sequence (unless you ask it to)--it seems to work fine with infinite sequences. For example: `(first (filter #{4} (range)))` returns `4`.

Comment: I did the same with `(first (filter #{10} (iterate inc 1)))` and it worked.

Comment: Oh yeah, right. `filter` returns a lazy sequence. My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think `some` fits the bill nicely for this purpose.

> "Returns the first logical true value of `(pred x)` for any `x` in `coll`,
>     else nil.  One common idiom is to use a set as pred, for example
>     this will return `:fred` if `:fred` is in the sequence, otherwise nil:
>     `(some #{:fred} coll)`"